# Control Screen Brightness in WIndows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, screen-brightness

Is it possible to to use c# to change the screen brightness? I know some apps can control it so if there is not a direct way then does anyone know of a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you don't have that level of hardware control, but if you only need to make the screen dimmer, you just need to scale down the RGB values of each pixel.

Depending on what you're working with, there are a number of approaches, but if you have a black background, you can just adjust the opacity of your front layer, which will effectively dim the content.

Comment: this is exactly (presumably) what the Kindle App does to allow you to dim the screen while reading